# Find an example of a stochastic process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Give an example of a stochastic process $\{X_n : n \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ on $(\Omega,F, P)$ such that $P_{X_n}=P_{X_0}$ for all n, but $\{X_n \}$ is not stationary. 
Here  $P_{X_n}$ denotes the push forward measure of $P$ under $X_n$.

I'm not sure how to start this. Any hints or examples will be appreciated! 
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ and $Y$ independent random variables with standard normal distribution. Then $X,Y,X,X,...$ is not stationary but it is identically distributed.

Comment: Hi, could you check if I'm understanding this correctly? The reason why our stochastic process $\{X, Y, X, X, .... \}$ is not stationary is because $P((X,Y,X,X...) \in B) \neq P((X,X ,X ...) \in B) \forall B \in S$? If that is true, why are they not equal?

Comment: @2pirsquared Look at just the first two coordinates of the sequence. The probabilities are not equal because $(X,Y)$ does no have the same distribution as $(X,X)$. You can take $B$ of the type $B_1\times B_2 \times \mathbb R \times \mathbb R....$

Comment: @2pirsquared You can also observe that $cov (X,Y)=0$ but $cov (X,X)=1$ so $(X,Y)$ does not have the same distribution as $(X,X)$.